# How to make a column take as much space as possible without disrupting other columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap v5.3, I want the first column to expand to the maximum size possible while the other columns are as wide as the widest cell in that column. Below I have drawn an example:

Current behaviour. Notice the last column has extra space on the right of the cell.

[image]

Desired behaviour

[image]

How can this be done ideally only using Bootstrap classes without CSS?

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, the grid system is based on a 12-column layout.

You can follow the below example to set max width for the first column and minimum width for the rest. View the snippet in expanded view.

```css
.row-all{
width:max-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
    <div class="row-all">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-8ssssssssssssssss</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-2</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-8</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-2</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-8sssssssss</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-2</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-8</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-2</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-2</div>
    </div>
</div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I dont want predefined sizes (like col-lg-2). I need the column to automatically resize to fit the cell with the widest content (without word wrap).

Comment: Ok, then you need to do it with the custom CSS. I have added CSS to the code above.